# Accessing portlets in Liferay Mobile App Using Liferay SDK

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.2 on my system and I created a site and some portlets. Now I want to use the same site in mobile application. I searched on internet about mobile application that uses liferay services.
If I create a mobile application using liferay SDK. Is it possible to communicate with portlets which I created in desktop site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already know that LR 6.2 theme system is powered by bootstrap, so if the portlet of your markup is well written you can have a great view of the website in a mobile environment.

Speaking about a native mobile application, I think you are referring not to Liferay SDK, but to [Liferay Mobile SDK](https://web.archive.org/web/20151019041544/http://www.liferay.com:80/it/community/liferay-projects/liferay-mobile-sdk/overview).
In this case you will be able to access to your data by using API it provide to you. In fact, it wraps Liferay JSON web services.

An other option for you is to use any other kind of way to write your mobile application and to write inside also a client for accessing to Liferay JSON web services.

These options start from a basic concept: your portlet make used [Liferay Service Layer](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018178911-Introduction-to-Service-Builder-and-Services-?notice=1) to provide data access. In this case you just need to be sure that you declared your services also as "remote". If not just modify your service.xml file and relaunch the build-service.

If you not used LR service layer (and don't want to use it), just create a service layer (without tables) with one method for any your external calls.

If you not used (and won't use) Liferay service layer, you just need to create a RESTfull resource listener, and manage your remote calls in this way.

Last, don't forget that Liferay core services are already exposed as JSON services (so you can call it by Mobile SDK or with any client of your app)... by the way, starting from LR 6.2, there are [some differences](https://www.liferay.com/it/web/tomas.polesovsky/blog/-/blogs/json-ws-security) in accessing to these methods for guest users.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Custom Remote Web services, Via Http You can call that service and communicate with portel using Liferay-mobile-SDK.